# For loop not executing all code - no errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

https://simmer.io/@JammerLamma/~c09dd45e-0528-01ce-e641-e4a56fb9cfed

https://github.com/JammerLamma/Number-Muncher-Clone

I'm creating a number munchers clone, and the integer variables are not getting properly assigned.  It works for a few games, but after a few times of winning, and/or clicking quit, and choosing another game it appears the for loop goes through properly.  The game says there are 5 maxCorrect, and correctOnBoard is also set to 5, so I assume the loop goes through 5 times, however, only 4 tiles get set as correct, then sometimes 2, or 4, but never 5 again.  It always works as intended the first game.

If I comment out //AssignRest(); the problem still persists.

```
public void GenerateEven()
{
    //GameObject smasher = Instantiate(smasherPF, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    remainingNumbers = totalTiles - maxCorrect;
    GetLists();
    GetTiles();
    AssignEven();
    RemoveDuplicates(evenNumbers);
    AssignRest();
}

private void AssignEven()
{
    int maxCorrect = 5;
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxCorrect; i++)
    {
        randomChild = children[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, children.Count)];
        int maxLength = evenNumbers.Count;
        int tempTileNum = evenNumbers[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, maxLength)];
        randomChild.GetComponent<Tile>()._TileNumber = tempTileNum;
        randomChild.GetComponent<Tile>()._IsCorrect = true;
        correctOnBoard++;
        randomChild.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = numberSprite[tempTileNum - 1];
        Debug.Log(tempTileNum);
    }
}
```

Some things are serialized for debugging purposes.  All of the lists get generated correctly.

Comment: How do you ensure that of the five random tiles the same one isn’t selected twice? If that happened you would only end up with four (or less) when the loop is complete.

Comment: Oh my gosh you're probably right.  There's no check for that, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: One simple way to do it is to assign each tile a random floating point number, then choose the five with the smallest numbers. That way it is guaranteed to pick five unique tiles and it's still random.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to

```
private void AssignEven()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxCorrect;)
    {
        randomChild = children[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, children.Count)];

        if(randomChild.GetComponent<Tile>()._IsCorrect == false)
        {
            int maxLength = evenNumbers.Count;
            int tempTileNum = evenNumbers[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, maxLength)];
            randomChild.GetComponent<Tile>()._TileNumber = tempTileNum;
            randomChild.GetComponent<Tile>()._IsCorrect = true;
            correctOnBoard++;
            randomChild.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = numberSprite[tempTileNum - 1];
            Debug.Log(tempTileNum);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to John Wu!